# Error "Ensure kernel-qemu is in the same location as your system image"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2019

Yesterday I decided to try out VS2019 for Xamarin projects, so I created a `Xamarin.Forms` project and selected *Master-Detail* template.

Once it was created, I simply debug it (F5) and I see the test app in the *Android emulator*. Everything works fine.

Today, I try to run the app again, I have changed absolutely nothing in the code. I rebuild the solution and it builds successfully.

When I run the app, it fails for this reason:

```
1>Starting deployment to Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo ...
1>Starting emulator Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo ...
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator.EXE -no-boot-anim -avd Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo -prop monodroid.avdname=Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo
1>emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file! Please ensure the file "kernel-qemu" is in the same location as your system image.
1>emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is undefined
1>Emulator Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo cannot be started.
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

The only solutions I have found deal with Android Studio, but I'm using `Visual Studio 2019`.

What can the issue be?

Comment: Can you debug it in iOS platform?

Comment: I cannot debug in iOS platform.